# Rewrite another users message

Tags: irc, mirc

I use MIRC and this is my goal, i'm sure it's simple! thanks guys.

```
    on $*:text:*test*:#: { msg $chan "Entire message containing test" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the `$` after the `on`, it's only used when you use regex to match (see [here](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/on_event#RegEx_text_pattern)).

And indeed it's quite simple, use `$1-` to match he whole message. `$1` will match the first 'token'.

In your example sentence `Entire message containing test`, `$1` will rerturn `Entire` assuming you did not use a `tokenize` before and because the default delimiter is a space in mSL. `$2` will retrurn `message` and so on.

[Here](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/token_manipulation) is a great article about token manipulation and in your mIRC client you can use the command `/help $1-` to learn more about remote identifiers.

Comment: Your awesome,that was very helpful!